# Recover uninstalled ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I accidently selected Ubuntu instead of Windows from the os-uninstaller app and I didn't notice my choice and I proceed with it. Browsing through the files that I have on my deleted partition I see an a deleted_os folder that has everything there. So my question is can I recover my OS somehow? Please say yes.

Comment: I do not understand: is the partition deleted? Is everything still there?

Comment: well when I go in the partition there are couple of folders: 'deleted_os', 'dev', 'proc', 'run', 'sys' and '.cache'

Comment: So if i understand you have no lost of data.  If this is the case just reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: If it was me, & I was not sure how to go with this, I would backup all the files to an external USB hard drive, make sure all files were ok from a live cdrom/usb, re-install with format to the deleted partition, than restore files from backup. This would be a safe route.

Comment: I just browsed through the files in 'deleted_os' and they are just empty folders, seems like the contents are deleted.

Comment: In that case, next time around, get an external USB hard drive and backup. Or if you have a 2nd hard drive you could use that too.

Comment: so there is no possible way to recover?

Comment: No simple way. There are recovery tools about, but I have never been in your situation. If you really need those files, I could point you to a near answer, but I do not have all the answers. It would need to save the partition as an image file on some storage device, so its a safe copy.

Comment: yea, I need my project folder to be recovered, I did a lot of work and didnt push my changes :X so if there is a way to recover that folder I would still be happy

Comment: You may be able to recover files from [easeus](https://www.easeus.com/) but I think free version only allows 1GB recovery. But I`m not sure whether it will work on ext4 also. But you can try once.

Comment: What is the "os-uninstaller app" ??

Comment: How much data was in the project folder & what size was the partition that was lost, data & total size

Comment: 253MB the project folder and the partition was 113gb the files that are currently in the partition are 2.1gb

Comment: There are recovery tools for Linux, testdisk and photorec are two main ones.  To use them well, requires research on how to use them.  Do not touch that partition till you are ready.  Professional recovery might be needed/wanted if data is very important.  Would also prevent Windows from doing any updates/upgrades, to prevent any further damaged to lost partition.